# FixedSys & Terminal Fonts

Tags: html, css

How come the font FixedSys and Terminal ONLY work on FireFox and not on any other major browser?

What's the deal? Is it because they are system fonts or am I missing something?

Thanks

Comment: They don't work on any of the browsers on my Mac.

Comment: I'll take a stab and say they are System fonts so they will only work on Window computers. Although Macs have Lucida Console, right?

Comment: Are you positive it doesn't work on at least IE?

Comment: I'd like to be able to use it too. I wonder if there's a Web font available for FixedSys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How come the font FixedSys and
>   Terminal ONLY work on FireFox and not
>   on any other major browser?
>
> What's the deal? Is it because they
>   are system fonts or am I missing
>   something?

The fonts do not depend on browser, they should be applied if they are present on the client machine. If you can view it in FF, they should be viewable in other browsers as well. The `FixedSys` font is shipped with Windows and is available (Not sure about other OS). Make sure that you can differentiate it or there could be some other problem. Using reset CSS may also help.

Answer (score 19):

I know this is old, but I converted http://www.fixedsysexcelsior.com/ to a Webfont a while back.. the files are here:

http://jollo.org/archive/doir/fixedsys

css usage is:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'FixedsysExcelsior301Regular';
src: url('fsex300-webfont.eot');
src: url('fsex300-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('fsex300-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('fsex300-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('fsex300-webfont.svg#FixedsysExcelsior301Regular') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
-webkit-font-smoothing:aliased;
font-smooth:never;
}
```

Firefox does have a little bit of trouble rendering it in some instances.. but this appears to be a bug with many webfonts (fonts appear blurry when the browser is a certain size, normal when another size.

Answer (score 2):

Those fonts aren't available everywhere (for example Linux). If you want to display monospaced text, use `monospace` as fallback. It defaults to the standard monospace font of the system.